# Looping through a csv with fgetcsv

Tags: php, csv, fgetcsv

I have a csv file with 3 columns: **email address**, **first name** and **last name**. I have got the stage where I can print out the array using the following code:

```
<?php
$file = fopen("testEmails.csv","r");

while(! feof($file))
{
print_r(fgetcsv($file));
}

fclose($file);
?>
```

This prints the array, so every field in a row. What I want it to print is purely the values in the first column of the row. How would this be done, documentation on fgetcsv seems very sketchy to me (a relative beginner).

Thanks.

Comment: Did you check official help? http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The first example in the [`fgetcsv()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php) documentation contains the nuggets of what you need.

```php
$file = fopen("testEmails.csv","r");

while (($data = fgetcsv($file)) !== FALSE)
{
    echo "email address " . $data[0];
}
```

`fgetcsv()` returns a numerically indexed array of representing the columns, so you just want to print the first column.

Comment: don't use filename instead of file, instead, wrap all this code this in `if (($file = fopen("file.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {}` as in the example on the link

Answer (score 1):

You're quite close. You could just print the first column since you already have the array.

But, you could also use `fgetcsv` itself as the control variable for the loop.

```
while (($array = fgetcsv($file)) !== FALSE) {
      print_r($array[0]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `print_r` you may try `echo`

```
<?php
$file = fopen("testEmails.csv","r");

while(! feof($file))
{
echo fgets($file). "<br />";
}

fclose($file);
?>
```