# CSV generating a table to e-mail

Tags: php, wordpress, csv, email

We have a WordPress site, and it is using SemRUSH API, which returns a request in CSV.  I need to e-mail that request, and have it be readble, as right now I am just sending the response, so it comes in like

Database;Domain;Rank;Organic Keywords;Organic Traffic;Organic Cost;Adwords Keywords;Adwords Traffic;Adwords Cost;PLA keywords;PLA uniques
us;google.com;5;397712791;570450887;641270788;11662;2671447;3225368;138676;35275

This is how I am doing it in my functions.php

```
add_action('wp_ajax_mail_before_submit', 'mycustomtheme_send_mail_before_submit');

// if you want none logged in users to access this function use this hook
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_mail_before_submit', 'mycustomtheme_send_mail_before_submit');
function mycustomtheme_send_mail_before_submit(){
    check_ajax_referer('my_email_ajax_nonce');
    if ( isset($_POST['action']) && $_POST['action'] == "mail_before_submit" ){
         $response = file_get_contents('https://api.semrush.com/?key=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&type=domain_ranks&export_columns=Db,Dn,Rk,Or,Ot,Oc,Ad,At,Ac,Sh,Sv&domain='.$_POST['domain'].'&database=us');
        echo "$response";
    //send email  wp_mail( $to, $subject, $message, $headers, $attachments ); ex:
        wp_mail($_POST['toemail'],'Your Personalized Audit', $response);
        echo 'email sent';
        die();
    }
    echo 'error';
    die();
}
```

There is also a js file that loads that gets the input (the domain name and the e-mail field) from a form, so the api request takes the specific domain, and e-mails the specific email, that looks like so

```
    // $() will work as an alias for jQuery() inside of this function
   jQuery('#rankForm').submit(function() {
console.log("form submitted");
var data = {
    action: 'mail_before_submit',
    toemail: jQuery('#form-field-eed99f1').val(),
    domain: jQuery('#form-field-domainField').val(),

    _ajax_nonce: jQuery('#my_email_ajax_nonce').data('nonce'),
};
console.log(data);
jQuery.post(window.location.origin + "/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php", data, function(response) {
    console.log('Got this from the server: ' + response);
});

});
} );
```

then there is this code added to the footer.php

```
<span id="my_email_ajax_nonce" data-nonce="<?php echo wp_create_nonce( 'my_email_ajax_nonce' ); ?>"></span>
```

how would I go about taking the variable $response, which is the csv response from the api, and making it something readable in an e-mail.  Any advice appreciated, thank you.

Let me add a bit further, so I want to go through the response and make a table that I can email, but I have no PHP experience, I have found tutorials in php handling CSV files, but most of those are doing the opposite of what I want (taking data and making csv, whereas I have the csv and I want the tables)
Or they take a file and read from the file, not just a variable that has the information.  I'm not entirely sure if that makes a difference or if the answer is treat the $response as a file.

Comment: hi and welcome to Stack Overflow, please post more of the code you have written so far and have a look at this guide https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Hi, thank you for the welcome, and sorry, I left some of it out cause I put the ` ticks on the same line.  I should now have included all the code that is needed to replicate what I am doing, except the form itself, which just has the IDs of what the jquery is grabbing

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mail_mail.asp

Comment: not sure why you need the API file response. You could just take the form field values and put them directly into your `sendmail()` function?

Comment: maybe you are right, and I just made this harder than it needs to be.  The goal is this site http://devtcd.com/search-engine-optimization/  the first form on the page that says "Want To Find Out How Your Website Stacks Up?"

and the client getting an e-mail with seo information that is retrieved from SemRush's API, so my thinking after 24 hours on this assignment was get the information from Semrush using their API with the inputted domain field, and trying to format it to make it nice and legible. It's very possible I made it harder than it had to be

Comment: oh I seeeee OK. Yes, check the assignment criteria :) What does the API return? JSON? you could use a JSON parser function to extract the information you want to put in the email.

Comment: just CSV text, using the domain google.com in the field, this is what is returned:

Database;Domain;Rank;Organic Keywords;Organic Traffic;Organic Cost;Adwords Keywords;Adwords Traffic;Adwords Cost;PLA keywords;PLA uniques us;google.com;5;397712791;570450887;641270788;11662;2671447;3225368;138676;35275

which is hard to read, so I am trying to google and find something like
https://www.zimplicit.se/en/knowledge/convert-csv-file-html-table-php

but they all have to do with having a file input, and I am not entirely sure if I can just ignore fopen, and do what they do as the $message

Comment: Thank you for your help, I am getting close to solving my issue with a work-around, basically just requesting the column I need instead of Columns, so that way I don't have to sort.  That should at least buy me some time so I can learn how to go through a CSV properly with PHP.  Can I thumbs up you or something?  I don't see an option but feel you were helpful

Comment: I may be able to put together an answer now that I know what format your API is in

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following will generate an HTML email from your data:

```
<?php
$to = "somebody@example.com, somebodyelse@example.com";
$subject = "HTML email";

$messagePart1 = "<html>
<head>
<title>Feedback on your website</title>
</head>
<body>

<table>";

$x = 1;

while($x <= $dataArray.length) {
    $tableData .= "<tr>
    <th>" . $dataArray => $fieldname . "</th>
    <td>" . $dataArray => $data . "</td>
    </tr>";
    $x++;
}


$messagepart2 = "</table>
    </body>
    </html>";

$message = $messagePart1 . $tableData . $messagePart2;

// Always set content-type when sending HTML email
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";

// More headers
$headers .= 'From: <webmaster@example.com>' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Cc: myboss@example.com' . "\r\n";

mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
?>
```

Use this info to open and read your CSV file:
[Looping through a csv with fgetcsv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26864675/looping-through-a-csv-with-fgetcsv)